# Faster way to pass a numpy array through a protobuf message

Tags: python, numpy, performance, protocol-buffers

I have a 921000 x 3 numpy array (921k 3D points, one point per row) that I am trying to pack into a protobuf message and I am running into performance issues. I have control over the protocol and can change it as needed. I am using Python 3.10 and numpy 1.26.1. I am using protocol buffers because I'm using gRPC.

For the very first unoptimized attempt I was using the following message structure:

```
message Point {
    float x = 1;
    float y = 2;
    float z = 3;
}

message BodyData {
    int32 id = 1;
    repeated Point points = 2;
}
```

And packing the points in one at a time (let `data` be the large numpy array):

```
body = BodyData()
for row in data:
    body.points.append(Point(x=row[0], y=row[1], z=row[2]))
```

This takes approximately 1.6 seconds, which is way too slow.

For the next attempt I ditched the `Point` structure and decided to transmit the points as a flat array of X/Y/Z triplets:

```
message Points {
    repeated float xyz = 1;
}

message BodyData {
    int32 id = 1;
    Points points = 2;
}
```

I did some performance tests to determine the fastest way to append a 2D numpy array to a list, and got the following results:

```
# Time: 80.1ms
points = []
points.extend(data.flatten())

# Time: 96.8ms
points = []
points.extend(data.reshape((data.shape[0] * data.shape[1],)))

# Time: 76.5ms - FASTEST
points = []
points.extend(data.flatten().tolist())
```

From this I determined that `.extend(data.flatten().tolist())` was the fastest.

However, when I applied this to the protobuf message, it slowed way down:

```
# Time: 436.0ms
body = BodyData()
body.points.xyz.extend(data.flatten().tolist())
```

---

So the fastest I've been able to figure out how to pack the numpy array into any protobuf message is 436ms for 921000 points.

This is very far short of my performance target, which is ~12ms per copy. I'm not sure if I can get close to that but, is there any way I can do this more quickly?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using Protocol Buffers?  From the documentation: "Protocol buffer messages are less than maximally efficient in both size and speed for many scientific and engineering uses that involve large, multi-dimensional arrays of floating point numbers. For these applications, FITS and similar formats have less overhead."

Comment: @FrankYellin I have to because I'm using gRPC.

Comment: @JasonC what's on the other end though? If you define the protocol then nothing stops you from doing gRPC with a protobuf message that contains a `bytes` which is just some _other_ format like Arrow. And pyarrow can serialize your 921k x 3 array in 20ms on my laptop.

Comment: @hobbs That is a fantastic idea. I just tried it. I'm able to assign a `bytes` field to `data.tobytes()` in roughly 4.5ms. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JasonC yeah, I realized that I was using float64 with arrow; if use float32 across the board it drops to around 6ms. So comparable :)

Comment: maybe you can gzip the data too if you want to save space/transfer

Comment: @hobbs If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it; otherwise I'll throw up a CW answer.  Thanks again for that idea, btw, it's been working great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is just to send something over gRPC to another program that you control, then you don't actually have to convert everything into "native" protobuf messages; you can use a protobuf `bytes` field to store another serialization format, such as numpy `tobytes()` output, or [Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/index.html). This will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Repeated fields are written as [key:value][key:value][key:value]. For primitives you can set [packed=true], which will change it to [key,length,array-of-values].

The packed variant can be implemented significantly more efficiently using a single memcopy.

Comment: Great tip thanks; I'll try this on Monday and do some performance comparisons.

Comment: Ah, looks like `packed=true` [is the default for proto3](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/#packed), which I'm using. This must be why it was so much faster. Cool.